# Is it possible to intercept network traffic without having access to it?

Tags: networking, security, internet, wifi-configuration

It's been bugging me for a long time.If a attacker isn't on the same Network can he still intercept the traffic of that network? If they can how? What is it called?

Comment: Welcome to SU. You might want to edit your question to provide more clarity (and limit the scope). Its a big topic.

Answer (score 1):

The question is really vague. The answer is really "in some cases", but doing this is not trivial.

Covering off the most clear-cut case of " not on the same network"- large providers use something called BGP to communicate with other providers, provider redundancy and balance traffic loads.  It is sometimes  possible for providers to announce routes to ip addresses they should not, and divert traffic.  This can be caused by a misconfiguration or deliberately (there can be safeguards/mitigations that can prevent this).  Where abused, traffic can be rerouted and intercepted.  It requires a fair amount of resources (ie Control of an ISP/Telco/major player). Cloudflare has an overview of BGP Hijacking [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/security/glossary/bgp-hijacking/).

There are other less clear cut methods of intercepting traffic -

- Malware is an obvious one.
- Intercepting DNS queries and redirecting to a different IP.
- Attacking anything outside your network but in the critical path of the traffic.

Its worth noting that many (most?) governments (eg [NZ's](https://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/2013/0091/latest/whole.html)) have legislated hooks into ISPs to allow them to silently suck copies of data or worse (Google "Lawful Intercept" and "Wiretapping".  Compromise the platform and you get the data).

It is possible to backdoor hardware to give a well funded attacker an in.  Many western governments believe China has backdoor Huawei etc. Ni doubt the East has similar suspicions of Cisco etc.  (Certainly Intel Chips have some undusclosed functionality believed to be the work of TLA's)

Sniffing traffic sent through the air is another way. WIFI is often crackable, as are cellular networks (eg Stingray!).  China's hot air balloon over USA and satellite was another angle.

There are even more obscure ways data can be leaked.

Not what you asked, but if you don't already know about it, google the related concept of a MITM attack and a Side Channel attack.